# Excluding elements from an old array and creating a new array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that has 3 different values, I want to create a new array that has only the values that are smaller that 12 (for example).

```
import array as arr

numbers = arr.array([10,12, 12, 13])

numbers.remove(12)
numbers.remove(13)
print(numbers)
```

I don't know how to add them in a new array

Comment: What do you mean by only one of the values?... Do you mean any one value, or specifically the value you want. Please elaborate..

Comment: for example a new array that has the values that satisfy : i < 12

Comment: just wondering, why are you using the array module instead of a python list here? Do you have a specific reason? Also, instead of thinking in terms of removing items, it's generally easier to create a new array with only the items you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. Here's how I would go about it.

```
import array as arr

numbers = arr.array('i', [10,12,12,13])

new_nums = arr.array('i', [i for i in numbers if i<12])
```

You can also use the pop() method, like so:

```
new_nums = arr.array('i', [numbers.pop(i) for i,val in enumerate(numbers) if val<12])
```

Alternatively, you can just use list comprehension on a Python list, like this:

```
new_nums = [i for i in numbers if i<12]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

1. you want only unique elements from the initial list
2. the elements should be less than 12

Code:

```
initial_list = [10, 12, 12, 13]
new_list = [i for i in list(set(initial_list)) if i<12]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[10]
```

Explanation:

The above code first creates a set of unique elements from the initial list.  Then it selects the only items that meet the condition `i<12` using a list comprehension.

N.B.: If you are bound to use `array` module, [@Praveenkumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372515/3129414) is the way to use.

Comment: You say "array", but your question uses a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [10,12,13,14]
newarr = []
for i in numbers:
    if i<12:
        newarr.append(i)
print(newarr)
```

Use a python list and iterate over the previous list(Use list, not an array), check for the required condition and add(append) the results to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below if you want to stick with array only (I don't know why you want to do that). `array` and `list` in python are different things.

```
import array as arr

numbers = arr.array('i', [10,11, 12, 13])

print(arr.array('i', filter(lambda x : x < 12, numbers)))
```